# Where does $\sin 3° =3\sin 1° -4 \sin^3 1°$ come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) makes the claim:

"Though a complex task, the analytical expression of $\sin 1°$ can be obtained by analytically solving the cubic equation $\sin 3° =3\sin 1° -4 \sin^3 1°$  from whose solution one can analytically derive trigonometric functions of all angles of integer degrees."

Where did this equation come from? I did a quick google search and I didn't find much.

P.S. If possible do not answer this using series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from the identity $\sin 3x=3\sin x \cos^2 x-\sin^3 x$ by applying $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$.  Nothing special about $1^\circ$ or $3^\circ$

Comment: Oh I thought maybe this came from some more advanced topic

Answer (score 5):

See the [trigonomtric triple angle formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trig_Identity#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) for $\sin 3\theta$:

$$\begin{align}\sin 3\theta & = 3 \cos^2 \theta\sin\theta-\sin^3 \theta  \\ \\
& = 3(1 - \sin^2\theta)\sin\theta - \sin^3 \theta \\ \\
& = 3\sin \theta - 4 \sin^3 \theta \\ \\
\end{align}$$
Now replace all occurrences of $\theta$ with $1^\circ$.

Comment: Hello my dear friend. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can derive the identity $$\sin(3x) = 3\sin(x)\cos^2(x) - \sin^3(x)$$ by applying the angle sum rules $$\begin{align*} \cos(a + b) &= \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b) \\ \sin(a+b) &= \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a)\end{align*}$$

as follows:

$$\begin{align*} \sin(3x) &= \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x) \\
&= \sin(x)\cos^2(x) + \sin(x)\cos^2(x) + \cos^2(x)\sin(x) - \sin^3(x) \\
&= 3\sin(x)\cos^2(x) - \sin^3(x)\end{align*}$$

The angle sum formulas are also how one can obtain $\sin(n), \cos(n)$ for all other integers once $\sin(1)$ is known, as $$\begin{align*} \cos(n+ 1) &= \cos(n)\cos(1) - \sin(n)\sin(1) \\ \sin(n+1) &= \sin(n)\cos(1) + \sin(1)\cos(n)\end{align*}.$$

(If you have some experience with complex numbers, you should figure out why the angle sum formulas are just a consequence of $$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta),$$ so all this comes from just one identity!)

Answer (score 1):

Dummit and Foote show that $3^\circ$ is the smallest angle of integer degrees that is constructable. They show: $\cos3^\circ=\frac18(\sqrt3+1)\sqrt{5+\sqrt5}+\frac{1}{16}(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)(\sqrt5-1)$.